# ERROR -- was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: laravel, angular, http, https

soy un poco novato y al subir una pagina web al servidor me aparece este error, y nose como solucionarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pagina esta echa con Angular de Frontend y Laravel de Backend.
No me aparecía ningún tipo de error en mi servidor local.

En el servidor la web esta en la carpeta "public_html", dentro se encuentran las 2 carpetas: una con la parte de Angular y otra con Laravel.
El dominio esta apuntando a Angular (alfarim-angular),

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo un ejemplo de como se comunica Angular y Laravel

### Angular

**Variable global**

```
export var global = {
    url: 'http://alfarim.es/api/'
}
```

---

**Servicios**

```
getPost():Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this._http.get(this.url + 'post' ,{headers:headers});
}
```

---

### Laravel

**Rutas**

```
Route::get('api/post/sub-category/{id}' , 'PostController@getPostBySubCategory');
```

**httaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if($method == "OPTIONS") {
    die();
}
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Cambia la variable global url de `http` a `https` y comenta el resultado.

Comment: Ahora no me encuentra las llamadas a la API, manda 404.  GET https://alfarim.es/api/category 404

Answer (score 1):

**La solución al error** "was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint" **es colocando HTTPS:**//Servidor ya que por protocolo SSL viaja encriptada la información (JSON) que envías a tu servidor desde angular.

Comment: Documenta tus fuentes, para que se considere una respuesta correcta.